# SELECT STATEMENT USING SUM

Tags: php, sql

Questions about SUM.

I have a table

```
ID | JOBSITE | EMPLOYEE |  VENDOR  |  PRICE
---+---------+----------+----------+----------
1  |  Job1   |  CHris   | Vendor1  |  100.00
2  |  Job2   |  Matt    | Vendor1  |  100.00
3  |  Job3   |  Chris   | Vendor2  |  100.00
```

To query everything from just Vendor1 works great. I use

```
Select * From table WHERE vendor="vendor1"
```

It displays two rows, perfectly (well in reality it's more but this example would be two rows)
I would like to use SUM statement, but it seems that when I do, all I get is ONE row displayed, but the total SUM works good. I've tried a few different ways, but I either get an SQL error, or just a single row showing like this

```
ID, JOBESITE, EMPLOYEE, VENDOR, PRICE, TOTALPRICE
1,  Job1,     Chris,    Vendor1, 100.00, 200.00
```

The sum works but it won't display ALL the rows related to Vendor1.

Any idea how to make that work? 
I tried

```
Select *, SUM(price) From table Where vendor="vendor1"
```

That's basically what I want. I realize that code doesn't work, and when I do get it to work either I JUST get the total price colum with the correct total. OR I just one id row. with added Totalprice colum with again the correct value. But all I want is to get ALL the rows attached to the specific vendor, and then have on Row 1 Colum 6 basically. Totalprice. with all the prices added up

Comment: Show your query that is giving you wrong results.

Comment: In the table you posted, the second row has vendor "Vendor 1" while the first row has vendor "Vendor1" (no space). I assume that this is a typo, and that the second and third rows shouldn't have spaces, correct?

Comment: Yes typo. ALl I want to do is SELECT *,SUM(price) FROM table where Vendor=vendor1 I know this code doesn't work, but it's what I want. I don't want to se other vendors in the report. I want to see all ID's related to Vendor1 but with a totalprice colum added as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use an aggregate and a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT t1.id, 
   t1.jobsite, 
   t1.employee, 
   t1.vendor,
   t2.TotalPrice
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT SUM(price) TotalPrice, vendor
   FROM yourTable
   GROUP BY vendor
) t2
   ON t1.vendor = t2.vendor
WHERE t1.vendor = 'vendor 1'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/864b8/1)

To get the results, you want you need to use a `SUM()` and a `GROUP BY`.  Since you want the total for each `vendor`, then that is why you need a `GROUP BY` on that field. A `GROUP BY` combines all values that are equal to each other.

You need to use a sub-query to get the `totalprice` because if you applied a `SUM()` to all records, you do not get the correct result since the id, jobsite, employee are different for each record.

See a [SQL Fiddle with a Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/864b8/5) of applying the `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` without a sub-query.

Comment: Beautiful thanks so much for the explanation as well as the code. Very useful information moving forward to learn. Works well too!